# Ho to declare in header is overload operator in struct?

Tags: c++, struct, header, operator-overloading

I have a structure in which the operator template type. Want to make the correct announcement of this structure in header. Write the following code

**header file**

```
struct add_positive {
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T value, const T& now);
};
```

**.cpp file**

```
template<typename T>
add_positive add_positive::operator()(T value, const T& now) {
    if (now >= 0) {
        return value + now;
    }

    return value;
}
```

But when compiling get the following error:

`error: prototype for ‘add_positive add_positive::operator()(T, const T&)’ does not match any in class ‘add_positive’
 add_positive add_positive::operator()(T value, const T& now) {
error: candidate is: template<class T> T add_positive::operator()(T, const T&)
  T operator()(T value, const T& now);`

Can't understand what I did wrong?

Comment: Unrelated for now, but please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: you can't separate the definition and declaration of templated functions into different files. The compiler needs to know the type and definition at compile time to make the appropriate substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an inline definition:

```
struct add_positive {
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T value, const T& now) {        
        if (now >= 0) {
           return value + now;
        }
        return value; 
     }   
};
```

---

Note that you usually have to provide a [definition for your templated function in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

In the header the following should equally work:

```
struct add_positive {
    template<typename T>
    T operator()(T value, const T& now);
};

template<typename T>
T add_positive::operator()(T value, const T& now) {        
    if (now >= 0) {
       return value + now;
    }
    return value; 
 }
```